# Set value of DependencyProperty to ViewModel property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Not sure if what I want is possible, but I also wouldn't know why it isn't.

I have a user control with a dependency property (a `string`) which I define in XAML e.g. as follows:

```
<Window ... (EngraveUnitWindow)
    DataContext = EngraveUnitViewModel
    ...
    ...

    <parameters:DoubleParameterUserControl 
        DisplayName="Exchanger Offset [deg]" 
        DataContext="{Binding ExchangerOffset}"/>
```

The view model 'EngraveUnitViewModel' :

```
public class EngraveUnitViewModel : ViewModelBase, IUnitViewModel
    ...
    ...
    public DoubleParameterViewModel ExchangerOffset { get; }
```

What I want to achieve, is set the value of `DisplayName` to `ParameterName` property in the `DoubleParameterViewModel`. So I created a `Style` which binds the `DisplayName` to the viewmodel as follows:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="parameters:DoubleParameterUserControl">
        <Setter Property="DisplayName" Value="{Binding ParameterName, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

The complete `DoubleParameterUserControl` code below:

```
<UserControl 
    ...
    ...
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance viewModels:DoubleParameterViewModel, d:IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}"
             Margin="5">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="parameters:DoubleParameterUserControl">
            <Setter Property="DisplayName" Value="{Binding ParameterName, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ElementName=DoubleParameter, Path=DisplayName}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" />

        <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="LightGray" Margin="0, 0, 5, 0">
            <TextBlock 
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Text="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                Margin="5, 0, 5, 0">
                <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                    <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding ShowNumpadCommand}" />
                </TextBlock.InputBindings>
            </TextBlock>

        </Border>
        <Button x:Name="_button" Grid.Column="2" MinWidth="30" MinHeight="30" Content="..." Command="{Binding ShowNumpadCommand}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And its code behind (where I define the DependencyProp:

```
public partial class DoubleParameterUserControl
{
    public string DisplayName
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(DisplayNameProperty);
        set => SetValue(DisplayNameProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(DisplayName), typeof(string), typeof(DoubleParameterUserControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public DoubleParameterUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _button.Focus();
    }
}
```

For completeness, the viewmodel:

```
public class DoubleParameterViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly Parameter<double> parameter;
    private double value;

    public RelayCommand ShowNumpadCommand { get; }

    public string ParameterName { get; set; }

    public double Value
    {
        get => parameter.Value;
        set
        {
            parameter.Value = value;
            Set(() => Value, ref this.value, value);
        } 
    }

    public DoubleParameterViewModel(Parameter<double> parameter)
    {
        this.parameter = parameter;

        ShowNumpadCommand = new RelayCommand(ShowNumpad);
    }

    private void ShowNumpad()
    {
        var numpadViewModel = new VirtualKeypadsViewModel(true)
        {
            ParameterName = ParameterName,
            Input = Value.ToString("F2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        };

        var numpad = new Numpad
        {
            Owner = System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow,
            DataContext = numpadViewModel
        };

        if (numpad.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            Value = numpadViewModel.ResultAsDouble();
        }
    }
}
```

Just to be clear, the property `ParameterName` in the ViewModel never gets set. So in my code, I want to popup a Numpad dialog which shows the parameter name in its title bar, but the ParameterName did not receive the bound DisplayName.

I hope somebody can explain me how I can solve that. (or, that it is not possible, and why not if that would sadly be the case)

Comment: What's `ExchangerOffset`? Is that a `DoubleParameterViewModel`?

Comment: Do you have any System.Data.Error in output of your VisualStudio?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Sorry missed that one, yes that's correct. I updated the question

Comment: @sTrenat No System.Data.Error in output window of VS

Comment: "in this user controls viewmodel the ExchangerOffset is defined" -- wait what? You're binding DataContext to a property of your DataContext? That makes no sense.

Comment: What class is `ExchangerOffset` a property of, and where are you creating an instance of that class and assigning it to the `DataContext` of the usercontrol?

Comment: @EdPlunkett ok, I've got it, he just have dataContext as, MainViewModel, in main he have ExchangerOffset, and he's settng it as DataContext of this control :o

Comment: @EdPlunkett Hold it one sec Ed. I will put some more context in the question

Comment: @bas, the main issue is, that if you will set some property directly in control, your style property is ignored, because it have lower priority.

Comment: @EdPlunkett updated question, I hope that clarifies things

Comment: @sTrenat what do you mean with 'set some property directly in control'?

Comment: I mean, something like : <customUserControl Property = "SomeContent">, this will override your <customUserControl.Style><Style><Setter Property="Property" ..>

Comment: If `DisplayName` is set via an attribute, it will override a style setter (slaps forehead).

Comment: The first idea would be to create attached property to DisplayName, and from this property, bind to ParameterName. Or create new DependencyProperty, and set it from OnPropertyChanged of DisplayMemperProperty's metadata, then bind it to ParameterName, even from style setter.

Comment: @sTrenat any chance you can drop an example?

Comment: @bas instead of `new PropertyMetadata("")` use `new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("", onPropertyChanged, null, null)` then, from onPropertyChanged, you can set another property, so it will have same value. Now, you can bind this second property to your ParameterName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like `DoubleParameterViewModel.ParameterName` exists solely to provide a name when executing `ShowNumpadCommand`.  If that's the case, forget the property and just pass `DisplayName` as your command parameter.

```
public ICommand ShowNumpadCommand { get; }

public DoubleParameterViewModel(Parameter<double> parameter)
{
    this.parameter = parameter;
    ShowNumpadCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(ShowNumpad);
}

private void ShowNumpad(string parameterName)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

Get rid of the `Style`, and bind your button's command parameter to its owner's `DisplayName`:

```
<UserControl x:Name="EditorRoot">
  <!-- ... -->
  <Button x:Name="_button"
          Command="{Binding ShowNumpadCommand}"
          CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=EditorRoot, Path=DisplayName}" />
  <!-- ... -->
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Glad to help.  If you're happy with this solution, I'd appreciate you accepting my answer.

Comment: Well I thought to wait a bit, more folks will visit (and maybe reward you as well :)). Still refactoring your fix in once I reached success I most definitely will accept the answer

Comment: Sounds good :).  Just reply here if you run into trouble or have any questions.  Good luck!

Comment: I'm done, this really was a revelation! Thanks again! ps at least one more upvoter found your answer :)